# How to make a header touch top of page?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a header touch the top of my page, however there seems to be an automatic margin, even if specified otherwise.

I've tried specifying `margin-top: 0`, and have set `margin: 0` to the body as well.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
  <h1>test</h1>
```

Instead of touching the top of the page, the "test" header has an automatic margin at its top.

Comment: You can inspect the element using the Developer Console. By default, `h1` has some top margin due to *user agent stylesheet*, the styles given by the browser. In Chrome, it has **0.67em**. In Chrome, your CSS `margin-top` has canceled such default style. But it does not apply to all browsers. Which browser are you working on?

Comment: @Raptor using chrome

Comment: You can test the line-height of h1 by setting it to 1. line-height: 1;

Comment: @Raptor What do you mean by "it does not apply to all browsers."? Why not? In what browsers does `h1 {margin-top: 0px;}` not work? Can you point to an official source?

Comment: h1{margin: 0px;position: absolute;top: -10px;left: -1px;}

Comment: @MrLister No. I'm not talking about CSS won't work on specific browser. What I try to say is each browser has its own user agent stylesheet. That's why we need to use CSS Reset to normalize the look & feel for all browsers. For example, each browser has its own default font family. That's why an unstyled element may appear different in different browsers, especially in IE.

Comment: One more factor to affect the look & feel is the zoom value of the browser, which is client-side settings. To reset to 100% zoom, press Ctrl-0 (PC) or Cmd-0 (Mac). Sometimes when you zoom too much, your `h1` may appear leaving the top margin a bit.

Answer (score 2):

adding `line-height: 75%;` seems to do the trick:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 75%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Warning: the exact value depends on the font.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `line-height` for your h1 tag. Optionally set the `line-height` for body also.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1.15;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: For CSS, `0` does not require unit, that is `margin-top: 0`.

Comment: Work nice. Problem is that all other elements on the page are forced into the same line-height

Comment: You tried to reduce the body line-height and set line-height individually for inner tags.

Answer (score 0):

The header in not touching the top even after setting margins to zero, must be due to line-height.Try to set a colored border i.e. border: 1px solid green. If you see that the border is touching the top then the real reason is the space around text/font due to line-height.

The line-height is set by the standard css rules included in the html page to create proper spacing between text OR by default it is set to normal which uses a standard value. So if you reduce space around text using line-height property it will do the trick but i do not recommend to reduce it less than 1 : line-height: 1

Answer (score 0):

Use Uppercase letters and you will see that your element is already touching the top of the screen so it's logical that the lowercase ones will be sligthly lower.

```css
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>ÂtestË</h1>
```